# I've written a code to check whether python shell is running in 32bit or 64bit. But the code prints 8 instead of 64

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
print(struct.calcsize("p") * 8)
```

The above code prints 8 instead of 32 or 64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html), you're actually looking for `struct.calcsize("P")`. Uppercase P is the equivalent of `void *` in C.